# Multi column Validation

Tags: validation

I am looking to use Column Validation.

I have column 1(C1) as choices A or B, column 2(C2) as choices W, X, Y or Z.

If C1 = A then C2 must = W but if C1 = B then C2 must not equal W.

Is there way to do this using the Column Validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an if statement to check column values. The format is `IF(condition, value if true, value if false)`. Your values if true or false would be another value check. So if C1 is A, check if C2 is W, else check if C2 is not W.

`=IF(C1="A",C2="W",C2<>"W")`

Comment: Just a clarification.. this is not a "Column Validation" formula. It can be used as an item validation formula in List Settings. Column Validations can only use data from the current column.